# Create one new variable that is a logical based on multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

My data looks like the following:

```
var1 | var2| var3
"abc"|"bcd"|"cde"
```

I am trying to create a flag field to indicate if any of the values contains a string. Right now I have something like this but feel there is a better way to do things:

```r
create_flag <- function(data,field_name,string) {
  data %>% 
    mutate(!!enquo(field_name) := case_when(
      str_detect(var1,string) ~ T,
      str_detect(var2,string) ~ T,
      str_detect(var3,string) ~ T,
      TRUE ~ F
    ))
  }
```

I gave an attempt at a `map()` based function. The below does not seem to work as intended, in that it doesn't pick up some match cases.

```r
data %>%     
   mutate(flag = pmap_lgl(list(var1,var2,var3),~any(str_detect(.,"string"))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the way you use `pmap_lgl` I will only check for `var1`. Instead you could could rewrite your function using `rowwise` and `c_across` from `dplyr` to achieve your desired result:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  var1 = "abc",
  var2 = "bcd",
  var3 = "cde"
)

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

create_flag <- function(data, field_name, string) {
  data %>%
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(!!enquo(field_name) := any(str_detect(c_across(c(var1, var2, var3)), string))) %>% 
    ungroup()
}

create_flag(dat, "flag", "ba")
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>   var1  var2  var3  flag 
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <lgl>
#> 1 abc   bcd   cde   FALSE
create_flag(dat, "flag", "de")
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>   var1  var2  var3  flag 
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <lgl>
#> 1 abc   bcd   cde   TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much! Exactly what I was trying to do.